# Merging two dataframes to paste an id Variable in r

Tags: r, merge

I have an id dataset and a dimension dataset. I need to merge these two to create a new set of ids.

Here my sample dataset looks like:

```
ids.data <- data.frame(id.1=c(1,2),
                       id.2=c(11,12))
> ids.data
  id.1 id.2
1    1   11
2    2   12
dims <- data.frame(dim=c("C","E","D"))

> dims
  dim
1   C
2   E
3   D
```

I need to combine these two in a way that each id will have three ids below:

```
> ids.data.2
  id.1 id.2
1  1_C 11_C
2  1_E 11_E
3  1_D 11_D
4  2_C 12_C
5  2_E 12_E
6  2_D 12_D
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `crossing` on the two datasets and then `paste`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
crossing(ids.data, dims) %>% 
  transmute(across(starts_with('id'), ~ str_c(.x, dim, sep = '_')))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  id.1  id.2 
  <chr> <chr>
1 1_C   11_C 
2 1_D   11_D 
3 1_E   11_E 
4 2_C   12_C 
5 2_D   12_D 
6 2_E   12_E
```

---

Or using `base R` - loop over the columns of 'ids.data', `paste` by expanding with 'dim' column from `dims` using `outer` and convert the `list` to `data.frame`

```
data.frame(lapply(ids.data, \(x) c(t(outer(x, dims$dim, 
   FUN = paste, sep = "_")))))
  id.1 id.2
1  1_C 11_C
2  1_E 11_E
3  1_D 11_D
4  2_C 12_C
5  2_E 12_E
6  2_D 12_D
```

Comment: Thanks! The second option gives an error .`Error: unexpected ',' in "                                           FUN = paste,"`. is it because of the package version?

Comment: @amisos55 if you have an older R version, the `\(x)` wouldn't work, you can replace with `function(x)` i.e. `data.frame(lapply(ids.data, function(x) c(t(outer(x, dims$dim, 
   FUN = paste, sep = "_")))))`

Answer (score 1):

Using `outer`.

```
f <- Vectorize(\(j, i) paste(ids.data[i, ], dims[j,,drop=F], sep='_'), SIMPLIFY=F)
do.call(c, outer(seq_len(nrow(dims)), seq_len(nrow(ids.data)), f)) |>
  matrix(nrow=6, byrow=TRUE) |> 
  as.data.frame()  ## optional
#    V1   V2
# 1 1_C 11_C
# 2 1_E 11_E
# 3 1_D 11_D
# 4 2_C 12_C
# 5 2_E 12_E
# 6 2_D 12_D
```

**Note: R >= 4.1 used.**

---

*Data:*

```
ids.data <- structure(list(id.1 = c(1, 2), id.2 = c(11, 12)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

dims <- structure(list(dim = c("C", "E", "D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::map_dfc` and `tidyr::expand_grid`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map_dfc(ids.data, ~ expand_grid(.x, dims$dim) %>% apply(1, str_c, collapse="_"))

#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   id.1  id.2 
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 1_C   11_C 
#> 2 1_E   11_E 
#> 3 1_D   11_D 
#> 4 2_C   12_C 
#> 5 2_E   12_E 
#> 6 2_D   12_D
```